# How to prevent Flowtype from unifying types?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm hoping someone can help identify something I'm missing in my types below. I created a function called `match` that takes in an array of tuples
that, when identified, will execute the matching function. For example:

```js
type Fn1<A, B> = (a: A, ...rest: empty[]) => B;
declare export function match<A>(
  xs: Array<[Class<A>, (x: A) => mixed]>,
  ...rest: empty[]
): Fn1<A, mixed>;

describe('match', () => {
    class FileExists {}
    class FileDoesNotExist {}
    let matcher: (x: FileExists | FileDoesNotExist) => mixed;

    beforeEach(() => {
      const whenFileExists = [FileExists, (x: FileExists) => x];
      const whenFileDoesNotExist = [FileDoesNotExist, (x: FileDoesNotExist) => x];
      matcher = match([whenFileExists, whenFileDoesNotExist]);
    });

    it('should return an instance of whenFileDoesNotExist', () => {
      // Should invoke the function in the tuple containing the FileDoesNotExist class
      expect(matcher(new FileDoesNotExist()) instanceof FileDoesNotExist).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

The problem seems to be that the types are being unified. I'm getting the following error:

```
1406:     let matcher: (x: FileExists | FileDoesNotExist) => mixed;
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ FileDoesNotExist. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
1409:       const whenFileExists = [FileExists, (x: FileExists) => x];
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^ FileExists

test/fp.test.js:1406
1406:     let matcher: (x: FileExists | FileDoesNotExist) => mixed;
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ FileExists. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
1412:         (x: FileDoesNotExist) => x
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ FileDoesNotExist

test/fp.test.js:1409
1409:       const whenFileExists = [FileExists, (x: FileExists) => x];
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^ FileExists. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
1412:         (x: FileDoesNotExist) => x
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ FileDoesNotExist

test/fp.test.js:1409
1409:       const whenFileExists = [FileExists, (x: FileExists) => x];
                                                                   ^ FileExists. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
1412:         (x: FileDoesNotExist) => x
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ FileDoesNotExist

test/fp.test.js:1411
1411:         FileDoesNotExist,
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ FileDoesNotExist. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
1409:       const whenFileExists = [FileExists, (x: FileExists) => x];
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^ FileExists

test/fp.test.js:1412
1412:         (x: FileDoesNotExist) => x
                                       ^ FileDoesNotExist. This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
1409:       const whenFileExists = [FileExists, (x: FileExists) => x];
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^ FileExists
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing here. Does anyone see something I'm leaving out or forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

The type variable `A` has to be resolved to the same type everywhere it is used within `match`, and that is causing the issue.

If you remove the parameter and try to do what Flow is trying to do, you'll run into the same problem. You want the type `A` to be the most general case (which I'll call `Existence`):

```
type Existence = FileExists | FileDoesNotExist

declare export function match(
  xs: Array<[Class<Existence>, (x: Existence) => mixed]>,
  ...rest: empty[]
): Fn1<Existence, mixed>;
```

But this won't work because `Existence` isn't a class, so `Class<Existence>` doesn't make any sense.

You need the the `A` in `Class<A>` to be different for each element of the array, which isn't possible. Instead, you can use a wildcard type (sometimes referred to as an existentially quantified type), denoted by `*`:

```
declare export function match<A>(
  xs: Array<[Class<*>, (x: A) => mixed]>,
  ...rest: empty[]
): Fn1<*, mixed>;
```

Here, `A` will be resolved as `FileExists | FileDoesNotExist`, but each place the `*` is used, it can be inferred to just be either `FileExists` or `FileDoesNotExist` according to usage.

This isn't documented anywhere that I could find, apart from in [this blogpost](http://sitr.us/2015/05/31/advanced-features-in-flow.html), so I'm not 100% certain about its semantics. It might take a little fiddling to get the usage exactly right.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for the detailed response. The existential type does seem to allow flow to infer the actual type that is being used. This removes the errors that I'm seeing, but unfortunately, it is not able to catch an error that I add intentionally. For example, if I did something like: [FileExists, (x: {id: number}) => x]. In the case above, I would expect it to throw an error because `x` should be an instance of FileExists, not an object. But flow doesn't seem to pick this up.

Comment: Ok, that's annoying. The only other solution I can think of - which may also not be quite what you want - is to create a common base class for `FileExists` and `FileDoesNotExist`. Then you can use the base class as the argument type for the lambdas. You could then also remove the `*` types and put back `A` type params where they were.

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation Peter. We've figured out a way to make this work but it's not the most ideal (see the post above). I've created an issue on the Flowtype github page if you're interested: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3393

Answer (score 0):

The existential type was a great idea but the problem with it is that it doesn't catch errors when it should. For example, if I do the following:

```
declare export function match<A>(
  xs: Array<[Class<*>, (x: A) => mixed]>,
  ...rest: empty[]
): Fn1<*, mixed>;

const whenFileExists = [FileExists, (x: FileExists) => x];
const whenFileDoesNotExist = [FileDoesNotExist, (x: string) => x];
matcher = fp.match([whenFileExists, whenFileDoesNotExist]);
(matcher(new FileDoesNotExist()): mixed);
```

We should get an error where `x` is specified as a `string` because it should be an instance of `FileDoesNotExist`. However, flow does not catch this error. It turns out that there is a way to make this work at the cost of adding a declaration for each case. This means a declaration for the case where there are two entries and a separate declaration for when there are three entries. A declaration will need to be made for `n` entries:

```
declare export function match<A, B>(
  xs: [[Class<A>, (x: A) => mixed], [Class<B>, (x: B) => mixed]],
  ...rest: empty[]
): (x: A | B) => mixed;

declare export function match<A, B, C>(
  xs: [[Class<A>, (x: A) => mixed], [Class<B>, (x: B) => mixed], [Class<C>, (x: C) => mixed]],
  ...rest: empty[]
): (x: A | B | C) => mixed;
```

While it's a pain to write out a declaration for each case, in most cases it is unlikely to have more than 5 items to match on. I should be able to safely add a declarations for up to 5 entries. Going to the snippet above, this will catch x as a string and throw the following error:

`This type is incompatible with the expected param type of
string: test.js:xx`

It would be nice if flow would be able to infer this using the existential type.